# Could show the actual folder structure for flutter project without the dot

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image: flutter project structure contains dot]

the flutter project I just created always contains a dot in the subfolder of src, is there a option I can disable showing the dot ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio,

- In the project pane, click on the settings icon (Gear icon):
  [image: Settings]
- In the menu (Which will pop-out) deselect the **Compact Middle Packages** option

[image]